# Can't receive push notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I've generated an APNs Development iOS certificate and set my server to use it. In Xcode I've enabled 'Automatically manage signing', Code Signing Identity is iOS Developer. Push notifications don't work. I use Xcode 11.3.1.

Comment: Have you enabled push notifications capability? Please check the apple developer documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering_your_app_with_apns. Also have a look at:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server

Comment: Yes, I have push notifications enabled. The server logs “bad certificate environment “

Comment: From the apple docs: 403 BadCertificateEnvironment The client certificate is for the wrong environment. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/handling_notification_responses_from_apns Apple has two APNS environments development(sandbox) and production. For both you can create a certificate, you need to make sure you use the correct certificate with the correct environment.